# I Need to remove distinct rows from my table

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see by the picture all i need to do is to remove all the row who are multiple but leave only one

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpaDT.jpg

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of similar answers on SO. Please do some research first.

Comment: Which columns are equal so to be considered as duplicates?

Comment: forpos i mean the temperature column

Comment: Does this mean that you want only 1 row left with temperature `39.49`? Better post your expected result.

Comment: i need to clean my table from distinct row.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward but inefficient way would be to cross join the table with itself and remove duplicate entries as given below:

> DELETE t1 FROM my_table t1, my_table t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.time = t2.time AND t1.temperature = t2.temperature AND t1.activity = t2.activity AND t1.create_time = t2.create_time

Perhaps you could remove the extra equality checks in the where clause of the query if you are sure about the columns whose values can directly be used to identify if two rows are possible duplicates of each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a Row_number() over ( Partition by ID, Name, Temperature, activity,   Order by ID, Name, Temperature, activity, create date desc ). Once the Rw number is created, you can delete the other rows from DELETE TABLE COMMAND

I'm assuming that you want only want one-row per to create date.